# Dual control an output with a MCU's GPIO and a capacitive touch button (TTP223)

Tags: arduino, solid-state-relay, 555

I am a newbie in this electronic world and English is not my first language, please be sorry for any inconvenience I may create. It was a long story for me to come up with this writing, let get a bit of understanding on my case first:

1. **Background requirement:** Design a Solid state relay to switch on/off home AC low wattage devices (less than 600W) that:

- Can be turned on/off independently without MCU using a Capacitive touch button ([TTP223](https://www.instructables.com/Tutorial-for-TTP223-Touch-Sensor-Module-Capacitive/)) (here called as TTP223);
- Can be turned on/off using an MCU pin and if possible allow the MCU to monitor state of the relay using that pin (here called as GPIO).
- Both TTP223 and GPIO form up a XOR logic so that the relay can be toggled using each of the control line (TTP223 or GPIO).

2. Development process:

**2.1 Developing the Relay:**
Quite easy using a Triac BTA16-600BRG (this can drive a load of up to 2A without a dedicated heatsink) and a Zero cross detection optocoupler MOC3041 or MOC3063S. I tested load (inductive and resistive) of 470-500W and the Triac heat up to 45-50 degree celcious and became stable for 20 minutes after about 5 minutes of gradual heating up. I used the cheap Chinese triac (less than 0.15$). The genuine one from ST Microelectronics  is better and have higher capacity to capacitive load but cost about 0.5$). BTA16-600BRG is snubberless so I dont need a RC circuitry (but keep it safe to have a R/C pair if you need to drive an inductive load).
[image: BTA16-600B triac]

**2.2 Develop the control interface for the relay**
This is the most difficult part for me as a newbie. Google provides me quite some options and I came about the following version:
**+ Version 1:** Using 2 analog SPDT chips SN74LVC1G3157DBVR to toggle the outputs from the 2 input lines (TTP223 and GPIO) (this is similar to the stair-case switch)
[image: Toggle the output using 2 control lines]

This design worked well. However, I have no way to monitor the output state (on/off)
[image]

- Version 2: Develop a circuit to replace the analog SPDT chips. Google tell me that a latching circuit using NE555, CD1403 or UA741 (UA741 required at least 10V to work so I removed this option) can be of help
  [image: NE555 toggle output with 2 control line]

*With C3 and R5, the output will not be engaged at power on. C5 is needed for creating a sharp control pulse from input line (following advice from Swagatam at https://www.homemade-circuits.com/).*

They all applied similar approach

**THE PROBLEM:** To allow the replacement of the SW with external control signal (TTP223 and GPIO), it is required to have a circuit to act similarly to the physical momentary switch.
Without much consideration, I jumped into the search for "building a circuit to mimic the SW that allows current from both directions A1<->A2". And I came about the MOSFET bi-directional switch option. And this was the **original title of this question**.
However, from the forum advises, I found this option was a failure (I set up a wrong schematic).

- CD4013 toggle output
  [image: CD4013 and toggle momentary button]
- NE555 toggle output
  [image: NE555 toggle output with momentary button]
  Doing a bit further of studying, I found that the current flow in the switch was just from the capacitor through the switch (one way) at both presses (first press to turn on and second press to turn off). With this consideration, the bi-directional switch is no longer needed and I came about this last schematic as below:
  [image: Replacement of the switch SW with BC847]

Applying of the CD4013BMS is better than NE555 as the Quiescent is much smaller at 5VDC (~1 micro Amp) and it functions better than NE555 at powering on (no engagement of the output).

3. The MCU
   This is not too difficult part: I use ESP8266-01S as the MCU with a cheap power module (0.8$) and a PCF8574 port expander. The board is here and can support up to 8 pluggable relays. IO pin on PCF8574 (P0-7) are quasi-bidirectional so they can work both as input and output without a problem (I have tested successfully)
   [image: MCU top view]
   So the programming part for MCU is straight forward:

- Have an variable to set initial state of relay (at power on) as OFF (Relay_state_1)
- Screen the GPIO every 20ms to see if TTP223 is pressed and change the Relay_state_1 to HIGH or LOW respectively.
- The rest will be using Write to set the related pin HIGH/LOW via pfg8574 library
  [image]
  I will test this next week and post the result.
  So this all of my lengthy story.
  Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: No. You would normally tie both sources together. But for a NMOS bidirectional switch you need a floating gate drive.

Comment: I have the Source tied together, gate connected together to a voltage divider (around 2.5V). Vgs is about 2.5V!

Comment: Oh wait, you do. Your transistors are flipped so it looked strange.

Comment: I am a bit confused. What is Vgs when the FET's are on? 2N7002 needs like Vgs of 5V to re really on.

Comment: 2N7002's threshold gate-source voltage is around 2V. And it's not guaranteed that 2.5V Vgs is sufficient to turn fully on the MOSFETs (even if the datasheet says so). It'd be better if you use a 10R for R12.

Comment: One more thing: Is this really a bidirectional switch? There are two NMOS switches and both have the source terminals grounded. Do you expect the current to flow from A1 to A2 and vice-versa?

Comment: I followed this: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva948/slva948.pdf?ts=1618409732022&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F
(Figure 13). I dont use a general NMOS to trigger the back2back NMOS!
2N7002 Datasheet is here: https://datasheet.octopart.com/2N7002-NXP-datasheet-29344.pdf - Page 5.
Min Vgs is 1V, typical is 2V, Max is 2.5 V so I tried with 2.5 to see how it work!

Comment: The question is what are A1 and A2 doing when you want the MOSFET's to be on? The gate will be at 2.5V I guess. Essentially, whether the FET's will be on will be determined by the voltage at A1 and A2.

Comment: Vgs(th) is NOT sufficient to really turn on the MOSFET. You need to get much higher. Do a little searching because I know I have explained this at length many times. I don't want to just keep posting the same information over and over.

Comment: Okie, thanks mkeith, I want this set up to mimic a momentary button connecting between A1 and A2. First press the current will be from A2 to A1 and press again current will be from A1 to A2 due to voltage change in the circuit.. The bidirectional switch discussed in this question is to allow the current flow from A1 to A2 and reversely every time a HIGH signal is applied at GPIO for around 100-200 ms then turn low again!

Comment: What is the voltage range? What is the reference potential of both circuits?

Comment: Voltage ranges in the circuit are low V(A1-GND), V(A2,GND), V(GPIO,GND) from 0-5V (maximum)

Comment: When the switch is ON, A1 and A2 are both at the same voltage. Pretend for a moment that it is actually a mechanical switch. When it is ON what is the switch voltage or voltage range? To turn on the MOSFET's you will need to drive the gate higher than whatever the highest voltage is at A1 and A2 (when on). That is what I am trying to tell you. If the switched voltage ranges from 0 to 5V then you really need an analog switch IC, or use NMOS + PMOS in parallel with complimentary inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing! What I am struggling is to Make the relay in my other question work (link pasted below). But  I could not find an answer for it! Therefore, I am trying to ask question by question to reach a kind of understanding on how to move on to my final solution. Please be sorry for disturbing!
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/557215/ssr-controllable-by-independent-touch-button-ttp223-and-i-o-for-micro-controll

Comment: Minor thing but - please use '.' at the end of a sentence, not '!'. Lots of exclamation marks read as panic. I appreciate that English is probably not your first language.

Comment: Ok, will do as your suggestion. Regarding my problem, I would be very much obliged if you can recommend me a way to design a 220 VAC SSR (using either MOSFET or Triac with opptocoupler) so that:
1. It can work independently with a touch module (TTP223) plugged directly to the relay; and
2. Can work with MCU via 1 single GPIO
I tried to design the relay but I stuck at the point on developing a circuit to mimic a momentary button as mention in this link https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/557215/ssr-controllable-by-independent-touch-button-ttp223-and-i-o-for-micro-control

Comment: Do you realize you have sources tied to ground? If you open those transistors, they will short to ground.

Comment: I realised that already! I Dont reckon it until today and I replaced with a simpler approach using NE555 and just a BC847.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a photovoltaic array isolator, the usual optocoupler can't be used here. There are those IC that already embed a gate driver purposely for driving N-MOSFET solid state switch.

[image]

By the way, your 2N7002 has a gate threshold voltage of 2.5V, it means that at this voltage it "starts to feel", to put a transistor to a conduction required as a switch, you need to provide higher voltage than that.

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdxk28.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why not use a pair of P-MOSFETs?

Comment: I accidentally used n-channel already! That why I would like to ask whether my schematic is ok! I will have time to test it next week!
I followed this: ti.com/lit/an/slva948/… (Figure 13). I dont use a general NMOS to trigger the back2back NMOS!

Comment: I think that all user comments make clear that your schematics is not OK.

Comment: Okie, thank you for your all comments! I will make some revision!

Comment: I finally found an approach here:
https://www.vishnumaiea.in/projects/hardware/ttl-compatible-momentary-toggle-switch

Comment: @ĐặngĐìnhNgọc That's not even nearly about what you were asking for.

Comment: This is a long story Marko!
1. At first I thought of mimic the momentary switch (pls look at the 2nd image where the A1 and A2): this was because I thought "I can replace the switch with what can allow current from both way for a moment when triggering with a HIGH signal". That why I look for a transistor bidirectional switch.
2. When looking a bit further at the NE555 and CD1403 schematic, I discover that the current is just one way (from the capacitor), so the solution is much more simpler. No need for the Bidirectional switch, just a transistor in place. The 3rd image done the job!